# Eclipse not starting up after reinstalling (log included)

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I made a dumb mistake telling GWT to use my User Data Path as the place or my web archive, so GWT went ahead and cleared it. I restored most of the data and downloaded Eclipse again. Now when I try to start Eclipse, I am allowed to choose my workspace (I created a brand new one and tried to use it) but afterwards it just crashes and tells me to take a look at my error log. The log contains the following informations:

```
  !SESSION 2015-08-13 11:58:43.076 -----------------------------------------------
  eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
  java.version=1.8.0_51
  java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
  BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
  Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
  Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product      
  org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

  !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-08-13 11:59:26.157
  !MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.net (75).
  !STACK 0
  org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.net.
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:391)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:291)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:271)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2922)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$8(Workbench.java:2797)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:633)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Node path "Êþº¾   4   )com/camelup/client/view/signup/SignUpView  java/lang/Object  &com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/IsWidget getInput ()Ljava/util" is not valid.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferences.validatePath(SecurePreferences.java:361)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferences.node(SecurePreferences.java:95)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.load(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.<init>(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:84)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.open(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:101)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.getDefault(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:46)
at org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault(SecurePreferencesFactory.java:49)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getNode(ProxyType.java:523)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.loadProxyAuth(ProxyType.java:533)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.createProxyData(ProxyType.java:138)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getProxyData(ProxyType.java:127)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrateInstanceScopePreferences(PreferenceManager.java:292)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrate(PreferenceManager.java:260)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.checkMigrated(ProxyManager.java:404)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.initialize(ProxyManager.java:269)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start(Activator.java:181)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
... 39 more
  Root exception:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Node path "Êþº¾   4   )com/camelup/client/view/signup/SignUpView  java/lang/Object  &com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/IsWidget getInput ()Ljava/util" is not valid.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferences.validatePath(SecurePreferences.java:361)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferences.node(SecurePreferences.java:95)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.load(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.<init>(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:84)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.open(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:101)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.getDefault(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:46)
at org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault(SecurePreferencesFactory.java:49)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getNode(ProxyType.java:523)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.loadProxyAuth(ProxyType.java:533)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.createProxyData(ProxyType.java:138)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getProxyData(ProxyType.java:127)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrateInstanceScopePreferences(PreferenceManager.java:292)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrate(PreferenceManager.java:260)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.checkMigrated(ProxyManager.java:404)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.initialize(ProxyManager.java:269)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start(Activator.java:181)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:391)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:291)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:271)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2922)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$8(Workbench.java:2797)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:633)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

 !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-08-13 11:59:26.209
 !MESSAGE Application error
 !STACK 1
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.net (75).
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:291)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:271)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2922)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$8(Workbench.java:2797)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:633)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit: I did not add any Files to the new Workspace so far

Comment: Did you copy any files to new workspace from old workspace?

Comment: Reinstall eclipse again. With default settings.

Comment: I tried that a few times already

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is compatibility issue.
Please make sure you are using same bit version 64 bit or 32 bit type of jdk and eclipse.

Comment: How can I test this to be absolutely sure? Java -d64 -version tells me: java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode) and Eclipse.ini fourth line says: plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316 so both should be 64 bit versions right?

Comment: Oh and ofc my Windows is 64 aswell, so what could cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So heres the answer:
I deleted the file inside of C:\Users\myUserName.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security which was named something like secure_storage. That did the trick and I can start Eclipse again now :)